# How to resample a df with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample

I have a minute data for multiple requests. I would like to resample it to hourly and groupby the request so that i can get the total number of requests per hour

this is how the data looks like

```
    | RequestDate | Request | Count |
    | 2021-11-24 22:09:00 | Request 1 | 10 |
    | 2021-11-24 22:09:00 | Request 3 | 1 |
    | 2021-11-24 22:09:00 | Request 2 | 4 |
    | 2021-11-24 22:09:00 | Request 4 | 5 |
    | 2021-11-24 22:10:00 | Request 1 | 4 |
    | 2021-11-24 22:10:00 | Request 2 | 0 |
    | 2021-11-24 22:10:00 | Request 3 | 6 |
    | 2021-11-24 22:10:00 | Request 4 | 5 |
    | 2021-11-24 22:10:00 | Request 5 | 1 |
```

Output:

```
    | RequestDate | Request | Count |
    | 2021-11-24 22:00:00 | Request 1 | 14 |
    | 2021-11-24 22:00:00 | Request 2 | 4 |
    | 2021-11-24 22:00:00 | Request 3 | 7 |
    | 2021-11-24 22:00:00 | Request 4 | 10 |
    | 2021-11-24 22:00:00 | Request 5 | 1 |
```

I tried this but ended in an error:

```py
    df_groupby = df.groupby(by=[df["RequestDate"].resample('h'), "Request"])
    
    df_groupby["Request"]
    
    KeyError: 'RequestDate'
```

df with test data can be created as follows

```py
df = pd.read_csv("test_data.csv")
```

test_data.csv

```
RequestDate,Request,RequestCount
2021-11-18 00:00:00,Request1,4
2022-11-18 00:00:00,Request2,4
2022-11-18 00:00:00,Request3,4
2022-11-18 00:00:00,/Request4,4
2022-11-18 00:00:00,Request5,4
2021-11-18 00:01:00,Request1,4
2021-11-18 00:02:00,Request1,2
2021-11-18 00:03:00,Request2,3
2022-11-18 00:04:00,Request3,4
2021-11-18 00:05:00,Request1,4
```

Comment: Please, provide a code example to create the dataframe. It is really easy, this can be made in 3 steps. Remember to write code examples with the code format in the post: {} symbol.

Comment: @RobertoT - i have added the the code example for creating the test df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your groupby line is missing a some key brackets\parens, I think.

The `resample()` method is something that gets applied to a `groupby` object, and so it should come after the `groupby()` is completely closed. That is, in general it would be `df.groupby(...).resample(...)`, but you have the resample inside the groupby.

For the resample, you also need the `RequestDate` column to be your index (it may be in your example, but if not you need to do `df = df.set_index('RequestDate')`). Then you do the groupby on the Request column.

The RequestDate also needs to be saved as a datetime if it isn't already

All in all, I think you can get what you want like this:

```py
df['RequestDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['RequestDate']) # makes the column a datetime column, needed for resample
df = df.set_index('RequestDate')
df_grp = df.groupby('Request').resample('h').sum()
print(df_grp)
```

This gives the below. You'll notice that the columns aren't in the order you originally wanted: It looks like `Request` and `RequestDate` are set us as the multi-index. I'm sure you can tinker with rearranging them if need be, or go with this.

```py
Request RequestDate Count
 Request 1  2021-11-24 22:00:00 14
 Request 2  2021-11-24 22:00:00 4
 Request 3  2021-11-24 22:00:00 7
 Request 4  2021-11-24 22:00:00 10
 Request 5  2021-11-24 22:00:00 1
```

Comment: Thank you @scotscotmcc. When i used this i realized that the actual data had few dates in 2022 and it was showing 0 for all the dates that were not present in that range till 2022.